# Android push notification not working when app is killed in OREO

Tags: android, push-notification, android-8.0-oreo

I am using FCM along with PHP to send notification. It is working fine when,

- App is in foreground, background **and killed** (below oreo )
- App is in
  foreground, background and **not when killed**(in oreo)

I even tried creating Notification Channel and tried removing 'notification' from php script too but nothing works.I have tried all the duplicate answers in SO but nothing works. Any help would be great. Thanks. 
Here is my code,

```
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void sendNotification1(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e("remoteMessage", remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashActivity.class);
        resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
                0 /* Request code */, resultIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Uri defaultsound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        OreoNotification oreoNotification = new OreoNotification(this);
        Notification.Builder builder = oreoNotification.getOreoNotification(title, body, pendingIntent, defaultsound, String.valueOf(R.drawable.appicon3copy));

        int i = 0;
        oreoNotification.getManager().notify(i, builder.build());

}
```

Here is the OreoNotification Class,

```
public class OreoNotification extends ContextWrapper {

private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "Fcm Test";
private static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "Fcm Test";
private NotificationManager notificationManager;

public OreoNotification(Context base) {
    super(base);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        createChannel();
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void createChannel() {
    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,
            CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
    channel.setDescription("Fcm Test channel for app test FCM");
    channel.enableLights(true);
    channel.enableVibration(true);
    channel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
    channel.setShowBadge(false);
    channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    getManager().createNotificationChannel(channel);
}

public NotificationManager getManager() {
    if (notificationManager == null) {
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    }

    return notificationManager;
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public Notification.Builder getOreoNotification(String title, String body, PendingIntent pendingIntent, Uri soundUri, String icon) {
    return new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.appicon3copy)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
}
```

}

Here is the part of my PHP Script,

```
    $msg = array
 (
 'body' => utf8_encode('Firebase Push Notification'),
 'title' => utf8_encode('Anusha Kumar'),
 'click_action' =>  ('.SplashActivity'), 
 );

  $fields = array
 (
     'to' => $_REQUEST['token'],
     'notification' => $msg , // tried removing this line too but doesn't work
     'data'=>$msg,

 );
```

Comment: are you testing on any of following device manufactures appo, vivo?

Comment: @akshay_shahane yes, On OnePlus

Comment: Are you using JobIntentService to start the FCM service?

Comment: I guess your are doin' it all wrong. you have to extend `FirebaseMessagingService` and override the `onMessageReceived` method. this service will receive notification anytime.

Comment: @AliZeynali I didn't post the full code. Yes, I have the class that extends FirebaseMessagingService and it has OnMessageReceived Method. Without that ,how I will be able to receive notifications normally in all devices below oreo?

Comment: @Arun No, I used FirebaseMessagingService Class and OnmessageReceived method is receiving all the data

Comment: @Anusha If you are using oneplus device, then check if you have any battery optimization feature enabled. If it is enabled, notifications will be shown only when app is in foreground. If not then your service is not running in background due to Oreo OS limitations. I remember having the same issue but in my case i was starting another service from onMessageReceived() and it got fixed after i switched to JobIntentService instead of a normal Service. Also check if you have latest firebase version in your gradle.

Comment: @Arun Yes, It's because of battery optimization. Thank you for that and do you know how to make it work rather than manually disable battery optimization for apps ?

Comment: @Anusha You are able to receive notifications in background after disabling optimization feature? If its a phone settings then not much you can do other than asking the user to disable it or exclude your app from it. Regular optimization will only take effect when battery is low or if the phone is in batterySaver Mode. User needs to enable Deep optimisation feature for notifications to be not shown when app is background. Not a lot of users will do that.

Comment: @Arun , Yes I agree but for me (OnePlus) user, the battery optimization feature is enabled by default.

Comment: @Anusha there isn't much you can do if its enabled by default. Frequently used apps shouldn't be affected. You can check if its enabled and ask the user to exclude your app by redirecting them to your app settings or battery settings screen.

Comment: @Anusha did y find a solution?